# Trying to compile in R (to HTML or PDF) using R studio in Mac

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, homebrew

I've installed R and Rstudio using Homebrew. I've installed Mactex also using Homebrew
In Rstudio there is the option to "Compile notebook" to HTML, MS Word or pdf. But I'm not allowed to compile notebook as I get an error:

> /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.5/R.framework/Resources/bin/R: line 193: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
>       ERROR: option '-e' requires a non-empty argument

I don't understand what this means.

I've also brew gnu-sed with default names, installed the packages `Rmarkdown`...

Thank you

Comment: I think the error message says that you need to install sed, a unix/linux text editor.

Comment: As I sed, I've already brew the gnu-sed. Maybe i have to uninstall it and use bsd sed... ?

Comment: Good one. Have you checked that  "/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed" exists? If it does, then the error is probably coming from sed itself. The program was expecting a file that does not exist.

Comment: A similar [recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074085/error-loading-aplpack-in-r). proposed the following solution run `xcode-select --install` in the terminal. Then give the installation another go.

Comment: @lmo Yes, you 're right! I've just created a symbolic link of sed to the location it was looking for and problem solved. Thank you! And my xcode-select was already up-to-date

Comment: This worked for me `brew update && brew upgrade r` found [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3839).