# Error loading aplpack in R

Tags: r, macos

I'm fairly new to R and I've just installed `R 3.3.0 GUI 1.68 Mavericks build (7202)` today. After executing

```
install.packages("aplpack", depend = TRUE)
library(aplpack)
```

I got the following error message:

```
Loading required package: tcltk
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Warning message:
running command ''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/tcltk/libs//tcltk.so'' had status 1
```

I've tried reinstalling XQuartz, but error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what the operating system is but this is an error that arises in some OSX systems after an El Capitan. Try running

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: In fact, this question has been tagged [tag:osx]. Anyway, +1 for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This error has been magically fixed using `xcode-select --install`, which reinstalls the command line tools.

It is suspected that this problem has something to do with the upgrade of OS X.